# scripting download of teradata files

Tags: linux, automation, curl, wget

I'm trying to automate the build of a server and am having troubles scripting out the download of the teradata tools and utilities for linux from this site https://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-tools-and-utilities-linux-installation-package-0. Anyone can create an account and then download after accepting the pop up license agreement.

I'm not finding an auth mechanism to pass via headers or cookie(i'm not the greatest at dissecting that stuff either). I prefer not to have to download it and host it somewhere myself as I don't know where or what access a server will have to corp network when built using my script. But they will always have internet access.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've also tried contacting their site support for help and just got a response saying that the site was created 12 years ago by a guy who is no longer around and they have had plans to update it but they keep getting pushed back and support is mainly for resetting passwords etc...

Comment: can you please give us a little more feedback in regards to your concern? - TD Community

Comment: I'm trying to script an install of TTU and am looking for a way to use curl or wget with the proper flags to automate the login, acceptance of license agreement, and download of the TTU package.